# How to set the linewidth for the subgraphs border

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

As shown in the figure,  when I set the linewidth for these subgraphs border

```
set(gca,'linewidth',1.5)
```

The linewidth of the lines in the red circle is not consistent

[image: plot]

The original code is as follows

```
clc;clear
nlon = [100:140];
nlat = [20:60];
data = ones(length(nlon),length(nlat));

figure
for k =1:4
    subplot(2,2,k)
    p=pcolor(nlon,nlat,data');hold on
    set(p,'linestyle','none');
    fun_fill_AA; % **mask**
    axis equal
    axis([110 135 30 55])
    set(gca,'linewidth',1.5)
end
```

```
function fun_fill_AA()
    data0=[50 10
    140 10 
    140 60
    50 60]
    data_lon=data0(:,1);
    data_lat=data0(:,2);
    fil=fill(data_lon,data_lat,[1 1 1]);
        hold on
        fil=fill(data_lon,data_lat,[1 1 1]);
        fil.EdgeColor='none';
    end
```

How can I make the borders of each subgraph have the same linewidth?

Comment: This question would be improved if the provided code was a [mcve] so we could run it, specifically without the dependency on your `fill_AA.dat`. You could [edit] it to use random data instead.

Comment: I run it in matlab live editor online and I don't get that effect (I used `fil=fill([110, 120, 140, 140, 110],[50, 40, 35, 55, 55],[1 1 1])`) Have you tried saving the image to higher resolutions?

Comment: @kikon
Thanks! It's better after saving the image to higher resolutions

Comment: yeah, matlab figures are hardly pixel-perfect in standard resolution; see [this post](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/296541-line-thickness-issue-linewidth-acts-as-an-integer) from 7 years ago - it seems things haven't improved much on this front.

Comment: If you have an answer, you can use the _Your Answer_ box below so that the question can be closed as resolved, rather than editing the solution into the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better after saving the image to higher resolutions.

left:

```
saves(gcf,'*.png')
```

right:

```
 print(gcf,'*.png','-dpng','-r600');%*//600 dpi
```

[image]